# Single-cell subcloning of BV-2 cells?

Tags: molecular-genetics, cell-culture, crispr, mammalian-cell-culture

I am trying to knock-out genes in BV-2 cell line. However, the majority of protocols require cell subcloning and expanding. I tried to subcone these cells and grow clones in DMEM+10% heat-inactivated FBS+1% PS (usual media I am using)+Insulin-Transferrin-Selenium. My cells did not grow and eventually died. Maybe there are supplements that I can add to the media to promote cell growth from one cell? I am considering using conditioned media from the same BV-2 cell culture after culturing them for a few days. Should it work?

Comment: Welcome to the Biology Stack Exchange. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information about the site and what we do here. This isn't a simple question and answer site, so things are a little different to more conventional forums.

Comment: We would need a few more details on how you go about your subcloning to troubleshoot why it isn't working.

Comment: As always, consulting reference materials is a good idea: https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/US/en/technical-documents/technical-article/cell-culture-and-cell-culture-analysis/mammalian-cell-culture/poor-cell-growth

Comment: I am growing these cells routinely in the lab, and they grow fine with usual media (cell thawing is always successful, they are not contaminated etc.). When I do subcloning i calculate cells so there is one cell in 100ul media. And then i seed them in 96-wp. After they attach i search wells where is only one cell in the well (subclone). And the next step would be expanding the subclones. I read articles where similar things were done and did not find any specific requirements for successful subcloning.

Comment: Are your knockouts lethal?

Comment: It shouldn’t be, I am knock-outing CB1 and CB2 receptors (separately).  There are also transgenic mice without CB1 (it results in 30% mortality in mice if knockouted in whole organisms). Mouse who doesn't have CB1 receptors in microglia cells are fine as far as know.